# Bind application pod and database pod in kubernetes

Tags: java, mongodb, docker, kubernetes

We are trying to implement two pods one with mondodba dn another one with java application. And java application requires to be bind with mongodb. How we can bind db and app when they are running on two different pods and with different subnets.

Comment: could you please add your pod definitions (mongo and java app) to question, so its easier to see your setup

Comment: Add setup files.updated git url to question.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) for your `mongo` pod. You need to add label e.g. `name: mongo` to pod and create a service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 27017
  selector:
    name: mongo
```

Then mondgo will be accessible from java application pod with `mongo:27017` address.

For a quick experiment you may use `kubectl expose pod _MONGO_POD_NAME_ --port=27017 --name=mongo`

This [tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose-intro/) may be handy as well.

Comment: i wrote in two separate files

one for mongodb np-mongo-service.yaml as below and similarly one for java application.

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: mongo
  name: venkatmongo
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
      name: mongodb
    - port: 9631
      targetPort: 9631
      name: habsup
  selector:
    name: mongo

But when i am running mongodb is working fine. But java application giving me error as required database binds.